# NSDate, output a numerical only date based on the user's locale

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this problem with displaying a date for the user based on the user's locale. But I want  the date to be composed of digits only. For example: 2011/12/04 19:20:11. The problem is that I've tried to use NSDateFormatter and depending on the locale it can display an only numerical date or one with words like this: Jan 1 2011, 19:20:11. I want the locale to only affect the order of the month, day and year. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I thought this was a poor question until I read the last line. "I want the locale to only affect the order of the month, day and year. Can this be done?"

A fixed date format such as `[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]` will not be affected by locale changes. The best thing to do is to use a '`NSDateFormatterStyle`' to do the heavy lifting for you.

Part of your problem was that you did not set the correct date formatter style. `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` already outputs the date format you want.

As far as the time format goes, if the user has their system set to 24hour clock then `NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortGeneric` should work right out of the box. But if not that can be fixed. The beauty of it is you don't have to check.

```
// Example Date Now
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
// Formatter set to proper locale by default
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Set formatter to short styles
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortGeneric];
```

At this point your formatter will have already setup it's own format string "`M/d/yy h:mm:ss a`", this would be for the US. So at this point all we have to do is change the format slightly.

```
// Remove the AM/PM from the format string
formatter.dateFormat = [formatter.dateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"a" withString:@""];
// Change 12h clock to 24h clock
formatter.dateFormat = [formatter.dateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"h" withString:@"H"];
```

Now your date format should be "`M/d/yy H:mm:ss`". Which is the version you would want for the US. You can confirm with a log statement.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:now]);
```

Note that when you change the '`h`' in the format to '`H`' you don't care where it is. So if in some locale they were to have a reversed time format it would be changed, but left in it's original position.